# How to change the source data for a chart in a chart sheet Excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, charts

all together,

I am trying to create a regional map chart that shows data per country. The data is provided by a dynamic table.
I created a chart sheet and inserted the regional map chart into it.
The chart now shows the data for the current countries, but I can't change the data.
The string mapInput is correct and also shows the right Range.
For example: "A4293:A4295,BJ4293:BJ4295"

The error 1004 comes up in the last line.

I also tried without "Source:="
And also without "chart"

```
    l = Split(ws.Cells(lastRowR, lastColR - 2).Address, "$")(1)

    mapInput = "A" & lastRowR - 1 - cCount & ":A" & lastRowR - 1 & "," & l & 
    lastRowR - 1 - cCount & ":" & l & lastRowR - 1

    Sheets("map").ChartObjects(1).Chart.SetSourceData Source:=ws.Range(mapInput)
```

Runtime Error 1004 “Application-defined or Object-defined error”

Comment: try `Sheets("map").ChartObjects(1).Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(ws.CodeName & "!" & mapInput)`

Comment: I tried it: Still error 1004. But now it says: The method Range failed for object global. I guess it has something to do with the chart type regional map.

Comment: Try to debug.print mapInfo. Does it look correct? If yes try range(mapInfo).select just to see if it does work.

Comment: What is the value of your variable `l`? You want it to be a column letter, but I doubt that's what it is.

Comment: Also, in a chart sheet, the last line should be `Charts("map").SetSourceData Source:=ws.Range(mapInput)`

Comment: Thank you @JonPeltier for your answers first of all. Sadly your suggestion doesn't work: Object does not support this method. And I checked the string again, l is set correct in there with first beeing "A" and then "BJ".

Comment: You said it's a chart sheet, and none of us noticed. Try: `Charts("map").SetSourceData Source:=ws.Range(mapInput)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't solve your exact issue, but I set up a working example. If you correctly specify your chart and your data range, it should work for you.

I have two ranges on my sheet, one named MapInputNE and the other MapInputSW. I have two "Filled Mpa" type charts, one embedded in the worksheet, the other moved to a chart sheet. The maps initially draw their data from MapInputNE.

[image: Map Data and Filled Map of New England]

I wrote a general routine to change the data of a chart, regardless of where it is. Feed it the chart and the data range, and it updates the chart, and also adjusts the projection and mapping level.

```
Sub UpdateChartData(cht As Chart, rng As Range)
  With cht
    .SetSourceData Source:=rng
    With .SeriesCollection(1)
      .GeoProjectionType = xlGeoProjectionTypeMercator
      .GeoMappingLevel = xlGeoMappingLevelDataOnly
    End With
  End With
End Sub
```

Then I made some specific routines to change either the embedded map or the chart sheet map to use either the New England or Southwest data:

```
Sub UpdateEmbeddedChartDataNE()
  Dim cht As Chart
  Set cht = Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(1).Chart
  Dim rng As Range
  Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("MapInputNE")
  UpdateChartData cht, rng
End Sub

Sub UpdateEmbeddedChartDataSW()
  Dim cht As Chart
  Set cht = Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(1).Chart
  Dim rng As Range
  Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("MapInputSW")
  UpdateChartData cht, rng
End Sub

Sub UpdateChartSheetDataNE()
  Dim cht As Chart
  Set cht = Charts(1)
  Dim rng As Range
  Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("MapInputNE")
  UpdateChartData cht, rng
End Sub

Sub UpdateChartSheetDataSW()
  Dim cht As Chart
  Set cht = Charts(1)
  Dim rng As Range
  Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("MapInputSW")
  UpdateChartData cht, rng
End Sub
```

Each of these routines defines the chart and the data range, and feeds them into the first routine, and the corresponding chart chart switches to the indicated data source.

Works well with both maps, though I've only shown the embedded one here.

[image: Map Data and Filled Map of Southwest US]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Chart Sheet, use following code to set data source:

```
Dim Cht As Chart
Set Cht = Charts("map")
Cht.SetSourceData ws.Range(mapInput)
```

Make sure `mapInput` represent correct data range

Note: Chart Sheet does not contains `ChartsObject` collection

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.

Sadly it doesn't work out. Error 445: object does not support this action.
The String mapInput is "A4293:A4295,BJ4293:BJ4295"

Comment: How your chart data looks like? What is the Chart Type?

Comment: In column A are all selected Countries and in Column, lastColR-2 are the values for each country. It is a big table which has filters and other VBA code applied to it. But the String mapInput gets put together right. You could use the example I mentioned above.
The chart Type is a RegionMap (140)  and I guess that is why the code fails.

Comment: Yes, Chart Type could be the issue as RegionMap chart is not listed in standard chart types in Excel. See following link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcharttype. It might be handled through some third party add-ins.